# How to derive an attribute value automatically based on other table values

Tags: database, postgresql, populate

I have some tables and want to populate a database attribute based on other table interval values.

The base idea is to populate the 'eye-age' attribute with the values: young, pre-prebyotic, or prebyotic depending on patient's age.

I have the patient table birthdate, and need to populate last attribute with a value from BirthToEyeAge based on patient birthdate, inferring its age.

How can I do this, or which documentation should I read to learn these types of things.

```
INSERT INTO BirthToEyeAge(bId, minAge , maxAge , eyeAge)        
VALUES(1, 0, 28 , 'young')
VALUES(2, 29, 59, 'probyotic')
VALUES(3, 60, 120, 'pre-probyotic')

INSERT INTO Patient( patId, firstName, lastName, birthDate )
VALUES( 1, 'Ark', 'May', '1991-7-22' );

INSERT INTO Diagnostic( diagId, date, tear_rate, consId_Consulta, eyeAge )
VALUES( 1, '2019-08-10', 'normal', 1, ??? );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join table `Patient` with `BirthToEyeAge`, taking advantage of [handy postgres function `age()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-datetime.html) to compute the age of the patient at the time he was diagnosed. Here is an an `insert` query based on this logic:

```
insert into Diagnostic( diagId, date, tear_rate, consId_Consulta, eyeAge )
select d.*, b.bId
from
    (select 1 diagId, '2018-08-10'::date date, 'normal' tear_rate, 1 consId_Consulta ) d
    inner join patient p 
        on d.consId_Consulta = p.patId
    inner join BirthToEyeAge b 
        on extract(year from age(d.date, p.birthDate)) between b.minAge and b.maxAge;
```

In this **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w89rmx6DF3GeeRMxicB6Ck/0=)**, after creating the tables, initializing their content, and running the above query, the content of `Diagnostic` is:

```
| diagid | date                     | tear_rate | consid_consulta | eyeage |
| ------ | ------------------------ | --------- | --------------- | ------ |
| 1      | 2018-08-10T00:00:00.000Z | normal    | 1               | 1      |
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Only made a change from b.bId to b.eyeAge since I needed the string. But it worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome @IvanRosa! Glad that it helped.